# How to Concatenate Dataframes if they share cell values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Currently I have two dataframes. One with a few filled columns including `Names` and a bunch of empty columns. The other dataframe has all the empty columns of the first filled. I'm trying to populate the empty columns of the first dataframe with the data in the second dataframe only if the dataframes share a cell value.

Example:

`DB:`

```
Amount  Foil?   Name                 Set           ....
3       nan     purify the grave     innistrad
2       nan     slayer of the wicked innistrad
1       nan     doomed traveler      innistrad
1       nan     fiend hunter         innistrad
```

`DF:`

```
eur     name                    rarity   tix    usd     set_name   ....
0.21    Ballyrush Banneret      common   0.02   0.17    Morningtide
0.34    Battletide Alchemist    rare     0.01   0.88    Morningtide
0.05    Burrenton Bombardier    common   0.01   0.03    Morningtide
0.03    Burrenton Shield-Bearer common   0.01   0.03    Morningtide
0.21    Cenn's Tactician        uncommon 0.01   0.22    Morningtide
0.05    Changeling Sentinel     common   0.01   0.08    Morningtide
0.04    Coordinated Barrage     common   0.01   0.11    Morningtide
0.06    Daily Regimen           uncommon 0.01   0.14    Morningtide
```

Now somewhere in `DF` there should be a row with a matching `name` and `set` cell as in `db` (`db` has only the cards I have while `df` has all the cards from all the sets I have). If so I want to be able to update the row in `DB` with all the info in `DF`. How should I go about doing this?

**The wanted end behavior is**

`DB:`

```
Amount      Foil?   Name                 Set            usd     ....
    3       nan     purify the grave     innistrad      .5
    2       nan     slayer of the wicked innistrad      .7 
    1       nan     doomed traveler      innistrad      .9
    1       nan     fiend hunter         innistrad      ...
```

---

### What I've tried so far is

```
final_db = pd.concat([db, df.loc[df['name'].isin(db['Name'])]],ignore_index=True,sort=True)
```

where my thinking was that it would concatenate (while ignoring `index`) `DB` and a new database with the same length of `DB` but made up of only rows that `DF` has. This did not work. I'm unsure what to do from here.

---

As an added bonus I would really like to be able to do this with a semi fuzzy search in case they're misspellings in the name.